# deactivate a logical drive to restore a jfs formatted drive

Tags: external-hard-drive

how to deactivate a logical drive to restore a jfs formatted drive that windows has activated without loss of data on the external drive. It was originally was formatted by a recorder in JFS format and when I connected it to pc to look at files on hard drive  windows activated the logical drive. now unable to access the files with the recorde

Answer (score 0):

[image: Change Drive Letter]

Click Administrative Tools, double-click Computer Management, and then click Disk Management in the left pane. Right-click the drive, the partition, the logical drive, or the volume that you want to assign a drive letter to, and then click Change Drive Letter and Paths. Click Change.

Source: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307844

Comment: The issue is that the recorder is by Panasonic and they have copy protection in place which requires the hhd to be registered. when I attached external hard drive to computer ( my error) windows changed it by making it a logical drive so I can not access the drive now with the Panasonic recorder. changing drive letter and path will not restore the original mbr the windows changed. I need a solution that restores or keep that saves the data that on the hard drive. @sunk818

Comment: I am not sure how you would revert back to a previous version of the MBR. There is a [trial here for JFS recovery](http://www.ufsexplorer.com/rdr_jfs.php). You can maybe try that. Also [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) may be worth a look. If you have the ability to clone your current drive bit-by-bit before you do anything further, you at least have a way of referencing the current state, or even reverting back if things go wrong.. Sorry, admittedly, I do not know much about JFS file system.